# VBA Paste Copied Value from Word into Next Empty Row of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Word Document with a few tables and I need to grab certain values and place them in an Excel File. There will be new Word documents each day to update the Excel file. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub copyTable_Button()

Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrddoc As Word.Document

Set WrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
WrdApp.Visible = True
Set wddoc = WrdApp.ActiveDocument

'Column 1'
Cells(5, 1) = wrddoc.Name

'Column 2 from table value
wrddoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 3).Range.Copy
Cells(5, 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

'Column 3 from table value
wrddoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Copy
Cells(5, 3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

'Column 4 from table value
wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(3, 2).Range.Copy
Cells(5, 4).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

The Excel VBA selects the open Word document and places each table value  in the appropriate Excel column. I don't want to overwrite any values but instead copy the value in the next row down.

Comment: The `.PasteSpecial` line has `Cells(5, x)` each time (the `5`, being the row, never changes).  Would you just need to increment that number?

Comment: Yes, the 5 would have to be 1+last import. I want to open a Word Document, click the Excel button to import into a new row, close word, open new document, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the last row number. Then, paste in last row + 1.

```
Dim LastRow as Double
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
' ...
Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```